# Using k-means clustering to classify sounds

Tags: python, android, artificial-intelligence, k-means

I am currently trying to classify a sound recorded on my phone, in python.
What i did up until now is to use FFT to get an array of 4096 samples from the sound, and send that to a .csv file.What I have is the label of the sound(i send that to the csv at the moment of creating it) and an array of values which coresponds to the frequency. The .csv file formating is like this

```
"label","values"
"WOOD","3.405,7.549,....etc"
"WOOD","3.902,6.921,....etc"
"CERAMIC","1.594,2.954,.....etc"
```

What I'm trying to do is, use k-means clustering to create a model in python, so it can group sounds after their values, and also recognise another sound when I'm testing it.

From my experience, k-means clustering is usually used for a few feats.I am trying to make one with 4096 feats.I searched a lot of possibilites but i didn't find how can i do it with so many of them.

Any idea how can i make it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I would smooth the samples, and possibly sample them as well in order to reduce the dimensionality. A 'raw' FFT is too spiky and random to be useful for anything.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by smoothing the samples?

Comment: Use a running average or so. Just to remove random variations.

Comment: So you are recommending me to take fewer values?

Comment: yes. 4096 is just too precise to be useful

Comment: I see, thank you very much, i'll give it a try

Comment: How did it go @PopCristinel? I'm looking for a way to cluster set of various sounds. Thanks!